# Set pygame.event Output as Variable

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm trying to determine how to take the output from pygame event and store the output into a variable that I can call on later.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
display_width = 640
display_height = 480


gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height),pygame.RESIZABLE)


if (__name__ == "__main__"):

run = True

while (run):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE
            print(event)
```

The documentation says that pygame.VIDEORESIZE outputs (size, w, h) as apparent from the console output:

```
<Event(16-VideoResize {'w': 640, 'h': 480, 'size': (640, 480)})>
```

So, I tried to store the whole output as a variable:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
display_width = 640
display_height = 480

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height),pygame.RESIZABLE)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):

run = True

while (run):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            output = pygame.VIDEORESIZE
            print(output)
```

But, no matter what resolution I size the window at, the console returns output as 16.

Comment: Sorry I'm on mobile so it's hard to compare but is there anything different between the top and bottom code? What do you expect instead of "16"? Isn't that just an event code?

Comment: On the second one I take output and set it equal to pygame.VIDRORESIZE. Then I print output. (The first one prints the event). Sorry I copied the wrong text. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `output` to the `videoresize` event *type*. You should instead have `output = event`.